# Including the initial parent process, how many processes are created by the program given below?

Tags: c, fork

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
 /*fork a child process*/
 fork();
 /*fork another child process*/
 fork();
 /*and fork another*/
 fork();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since in each step, the processes double, that would be 8.

We can modify the program to print some letters:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    /*fork a child process*/
    fork();
    printf("x\n");
    /*fork another child process*/
    fork();
    printf("y\n");
    /*and fork another*/
    fork();
    printf("z\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then count the actual number using this command.  Granting we have the code stored as `temp.c`:

```
( gcc temp.c -o temp && ./temp ) 2>/dev/null | grep -w z | wc -l
```

We'll get:

```
8
```